# in php, use curl or file_get_content to get current location through url

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, geoip

this link return me my current location :
https://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js which is Singapore.
However, if i use file_get_contents('https://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js') in a php file, it returns me United States. Why?

Comment: Because the server hosting the PHP file you are calling `file_get_contents` from is in the United States.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is executed on the server side. Your website hosted on a US server. so if you call a function by a server-side language it doesn't get executed from the user but from the server and uses the server location.

Answer (score 0):

It simple. JavaScript runs locally
When you open https://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js it run in your computer and when you use  file_get_contents('https://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js') it run in your server.